# Citrix VDI - how to verify working with a Golden Image?

Tags: citrix, vdi

When opening the Golden Image for updates, how can an installed software verify that it's running on a Golden Image and not on an MCS or PVS endpoint?

There are actions that you'd not perform on a Golden Image being booted, or specifically perform on it, and it doesn't seem like there's a way of doing that, either using a registry key or other parameter.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the root of the system drive (normally C:), there is a Personality.ini file. For PVS Clients 'WriteCacheType' determines the disk state. For MCS, 'DiskMode' determines the state. You should be able to write a powershell script that checks the value of the data before executing a task.

Comment: Thanks, @usmcguy, I'll check that!

Comment: Beautiful! It works as advertised! Thanks a lot!!!